# In aiterya brahmana, it is stated that animals like cow, camel, goat, horse, etc are not to be sacrificed, but other scriptures validate animal sac

Tags: rig-veda, yajur-veda, sacrifice, shatapatha-brahmana, bali

Many commentators of different sampradayas conclude that Vedic sacrifice is just. But this encounter with aiterya brahmana and jaiminiya brahmana maybe says something otherwise? Well I would like to learn about Vedic sacrifices, if they are valid, if yes, in what cases, and how can we interpret these texts (aiterya brahamana, &c.)